# What are metaphysicals, and where do they come from?

Tags: world-break

The series forgets even to introduce the strikers team members (we reach the summer vacation episode and you have to pick up their names on the go), and sadly there is no intro on the metaphysicals.

So, what are the metaphysicals (aside from being huge mithical monsters) and where do they come from?

Comment: Considering how little of that show actually gets explained at all, I wouldn't be surprised if the answer was literally "They're just the BBEGs".